# string literal and type as template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I would like to pass in a string literal and a type (a collection of types actually but one type can encompass them so just listing that case here) as template arguments. I tried the following options but none seem to compile. Is there a way to accomplish this using C++17?

```cpp
template <typename T, int N, char const (&arr)[N]>
struct X{};

template <int N>
struct W {
    constexpr W(const char (&arr)[N]) {
        for (auto idx =0 ; idx < N; ++idx) {
            data[idx] = arr[idx];
        }
    }
    char data[N];
};

template <typename T, int N>
struct Z {
    constexpr Z(const char (&arr)[N]) {
        for (auto idx =0 ; idx < N; ++idx) {
            data[idx] = arr[idx];
        }
    }
    char data[N];
    using other_type = T;
};



int main() {
    X<float, 2, "a"> x; // does not compile
    constexpr W w("this"); // compiles OK
    constexpr Z<int> w("this"); // Does not compile
}
```

Comment: Pointers/references to string literals are not allowed as template arguments. With C++20 you can wrap the string in a class type and pass that by-value as template argument. With only C++17 you need to store the string somewhere externally with static storage duration and pass a reference/pointer to that external object instead. Are you really restricted to C++17?

Comment: yes, w.r.t. restriction

Comment: Why do you need specifically a string literal for?

Answer (score 0):

As the comments on your post have already indicated, you are not allowed to template on a specific string

But you can get *very close*:

```
#include <iostream>

const char * hw = "hello world";

template<const char ** S>
struct StringCarrier
{
    const char * string(){return *S;}
};

int main()
{
    auto sc = StringCarrier<&hw>{};
    std::cout << sc.string(); // prints "hello world"
}
```

It doesn't work if you remove the second indirection - templating on `const char * S` and using `hw` directly doesn't compile.

Comment: This is my second version of this answer - the first one templated on a struct with a `static consexpr const char *` which also works and might be slightly more convenient, depending on what you're going for. You can also template on a `uintptr_t` and do some ugly casting, there are lots of choices.

Comment: Just using an array would also work, it relies on the constness of the address in this case vs. contents. 
```char z[] = "hello";

template <char *p>
struct R {
};

int main() {
    R<z> rp;
}
```